# How not to change the value in variables when switching between screens?

Tags: react-native

```
constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state={
        numberofFood:3,

    };
}
 this.setState({'numberofFood': this.state.numberofFood + this.props.navigation.getParam('quantity') })
```

So now I changed the value of the varaible numberofFood. But when I come to this file the value changes back to 3 because it is in constructor. I don't want that. How do I make the value not changed after using the setState method to it?

Comment: You need some sort of state management at an app level, have a look into Redux or ScreenProps in react-navigation